# Manhattan, Euclidian and Chebyshev in a A* Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, a-star

I am confused by what the purpose of manhattan, euclidian and chebyshev in an A* Algorithm. Is it just the distance calculation or does the A* algorithm find paths in different ways depending on those metrics (vertical & horizontal or diagonally or all three). My impression of these three metrics were that they have their different methods of calculating distance as seen in this website : https://lyfat.wordpress.com/2012/05/22/euclidean-vs-chebyshev-vs-manhattan-distance/

But some people tell me that the A* algorithm moves only vertical and horizontal if the manhattan metric is used and must be drawn that way. Only diagonally for 
euclidian and can move in all three directions for chebyshev.

So what I wanted to clarify was does the A* algorithm run in different directions based on the metrics (Manhattan, Chebyshev and Euclidian) or does it run on all directions but have different heuristic costs based on the metrics. I am a student and have been confused by this so any clarification possible is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, things are a little bit the other way around, *i.e.* we usually know the movement type that we are interested in, and this movement type determines which is the best metric (Manhattan, Chebyshev, Euclidian) to be used in the heuristic.

Changing the heuristic will not change the connectivity of neighboring cells.

In order to make the A* algorithm find paths according to a particular movement type (*i.e.* only horizontal+vertical, or diagonal, etc), the neighbor enumeration procedure should be set accordingly. (This enumeration of the neighbors of a node is done somewhere inside the main loop of the algorithm, after a node is popped from the queue).

In brief, not the heuristic, but the way the neighbors of a node are enumerated  determines which type of movements the A* algorithm allows.

Afterwards, once a movement type was established and encoded into the algorithm as described above, it is also important to find a good heuristic. The heuristic needs to satisfy certain criteria in order to be valid (it needs to not over-estimate the distance to the target), thus some heuristics are incompatible with certain movement types. Choosing an invalid heuristic no longer guarantees that A* will find the proper solution when it's done. A good choice for the heuristic is to use precisely the one measuring distance under the selected movement type (*e.g.* Manhattan for horizontal/vertical, and so on).

Comment: Thanks! That clears it up :D Just so i understand manhattan is the best choice when the A* does not allow diagonal movement?

Comment: Great! :D indeed, Manhattan is the best choice when A* allows only the up-down-left-right movements.

Comment: Thanks again! Really helped me out there :D

Answer (score 0):

It is also worth mentioning the **octile distance**, which is a very accurate estimate of the distance when traveling on a grid with neighboring diagonals allowed. It basically estimates a direct path from A to B using neighboring diagonal moves which have a cost of `sqrt(2)` instead of `1` for cardinal movements. In other words it is a kind of Manhattan distance but with diagonals.

A very good resource on all of those grid heuristics is found here

[http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/Heuristics.html](http://theory.stanford.edu/%7Eamitp/GameProgramming/Heuristics.html)